# Said of or said for

Tags: prepositions

> The same can be said **for** minorities

Or

> The same can be said **of** minorities

Yes. I havent provided enough context because i m not sure which preposition to use. So can u guys provide context and insight on how to know which preposition to use? You guys can give new examples too.

Answer (score 1):

Said of = said about them (good or bad).

Said for = said in their favour. "That idea has a lot to be said for it" (it's a good idea).